# Unable to create Hive External Table at a path with error (message:Illegal character in path at index 20

Tags: hive, hdfs

I am creating a hive external table at a path. And it is giving error:

```
hive> create external table mydb.ext_apps (
    > a string,
    > b string
    > )
    > location '/apps/sysDSPPRS/sysuser/temp';
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Illegal character in path at index 20: hdfs://namenode1/ apps/sysDSPPRS)
```

There is a *blankspace* at the hdfs path in the Error message `(message:Illegal character in path at index 20: hdfs://namenode1/ apps/sysDSPPRS)`

The hdfs path also exists.
Has it got to do something with this space, or anything with the configuration ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the space from your config?

Comment: also can you try to provide absolute path in create statement?

Comment: @OneCricketeer i dont know where the config is.

Comment: @KoushikRoy i tried with absolute path also..but same error

Comment: The hdfs path is defined by core-site.xml in HADOOP_CONF_DIR folder